# Equal vertex in a jGraphT DirectedWeightedMultigraph

Tags: java, equals, directed-graph, jgrapht

I want to have a DirectedWeightedMultigraph with "customized" Vertex and Edges.
With this code, I would like to have only three vertices because v1 and v4 have the same key, but I have four.

```
         DirectedWeightedMultigraph<Vertex, Edge> graph = new DirectedWeightedMultigraph<Vertex, Edge>(Edge.class);

     Vertex v1 = new Vertex("a", "o1");
     Vertex v2 = new Vertex("b", "o2");
     Vertex v3 = new Vertex("c", "o1");
     Vertex v4 = new Vertex("a", "o3");

     graph.addVertex(v1);
     graph.addVertex(v2);
     graph.addVertex(v3);
     graph.addVertex(v4);
     System.out.println("#vertex: "+ graph.vertexSet().size());
```

This is how my vertex looks like:

```
public class Vertex {

String key;
String other;

public Vertex(String id, String o){
    key = id;
    other = o;
}

public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (object == null || !(object instanceof Vertex)) {
        return false;
    }       
    return (this.key == ((Vertex) object).key);
}   

public boolean isAVertex(Set<Vertex> set) {

    boolean result = false;
     for (Vertex v : set) {
            if (this.equals(v)) { 
                result = true;
                break;
            }
     }
    return result;

}
```

}

My edges looks like

```
public class Edge {

int cost;
```

}

Before using edges, I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114449/use-equal-vertex-in-a-jgrapht-simplegraph) and [this](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode) about equals and hashCode for vertex and edge. I also try to use ParanoidGraph but it does'nt work. To solve that problem, I chose to "manually" check if a vertex with a specific key is in the vertexSet before add a vertex. But I miss what's wrong in my code. I still have four vertices:

```
         List<Vertex> rowVertices = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
     rowVertices.add(v1);
     rowVertices.add(v2);
     rowVertices.add(v3);
     rowVertices.add(v4);

     Iterator it = rowVertices.iterator();
     while (it.hasNext()) {
         Vertex currentVertex = (Vertex) it.next();

         if (!currentVertex.isAVertex(graph.vertexSet())) {
             graph.addVertex(currentVertex);
         }           
     }

     System.out.println("#vertex: "+ graph.vertexSet().size());
```

Comment: Now working ... but strange behaviour of `if (this.equals(v))` in `isAVertex()` method. In fact I have this conditional statement in two classes (implemented exactely the same way) but It works in one classe and in other I need to use `if (this.key.equals(v.key))`. What's wrong ???